# How to update automatically data from datagrid in flex2?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, datagrid

Here is the problem:

I have datagrid binded with data acquired from web service which, as you may suspect, retrieves data from some db. Datagrid has some editable columns and I want to update db through appropriate web service call without adding button "Update" as a last column in datagrid.

How can I do this? Is there any event which I should listen?

Thanks in advance,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the itemEditor events.  I would probably add a listener to itemEditEnd to update your database via some remote service.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event:itemEditEnd